# Share authentication state between app and a widget in iframe (i.e. Universal login)

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, iframe, next.js

**Context:**

There is a web app hosted at service.io, this is where most users would login to or create their account because it provides a whole boatload of services to the user. Users also have access to a widget which they can embed in their won website to provide their user's with the functionality from some of our services.

**Problem:**

Because the app and the widget will technically live in 2 different domains, sharing the authentication state is not possible. This means that whenever the users of the widget will have to login at the website where the widget is in, which is wrapped in an iframe to prevent anything from leaking. This is not ideal.

**Current solution:**

Since the problem is the fact that the widget would live in a different domain, I decided to host the widget under the domain where the app is (abc.com/embeds) and use the iframe's src prop to load that route (<iframe src="abc.com/embeds). To do this, I use what is known as multi-zones and rewrites via the NextJS framework (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/multi-zones. So the app would live under /* and the widget would live under /embeds.

The issue is now I have to use NextJS for the widget too, which is less than optimal because I don't use any Next-related features for the widget and therefore unnecessary increases the bundle size.

**Ideal solutions (from my perspective):**

The best and easiest would be if I could use the multi-zones + rewrites while hosting both applications on vercel but without using NextJS for the widget.

The only other solution that I could think of is to somehow synchronize the authentication states between the widget and app without hosting the widget at the app domain. I haven't implemented auth0 universal login myself, but I believe conceptually it's similar?

**Questions:**

- How would I go about achieving either of the above solutions?
- Is there a better alternative?
- Security-wise is the current solution solid? Or should I make users login on every widget?

**Visualization:**

[image]

Comment: You could use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between the windows, or if you end up using a reverse proxy or server to serve the frames from the same domain, use the [`storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) event to synchronize data over LocalStorage.

Comment: - how would i secure this exchange? How would I make sure that the messages from and to are from where I expect them to come from? for example, one user can have many widgets, how do I make sure that the relevant auth/widget info is sent to the relevant widget.

- on your second point regarding using a reverse proxy, what do you mean by "serve the frames from the same domain"?

Answer (score 0):

As was suggested by @cbr - You can use `postMessage`, Host Website (i.e your widget) will use `postMessage` to your app that is on service.io

To secure, do the following

1. Confirm `origin` when sending via `targetWindow` and `evt.origin` when receiving on your widget - This meets your need of confirming who you are sending to and the receiver is also confirming *who* sent the message.
2. If there are multiple `targetWindow` instances, simply name them and you can direct the corresponding message to the intended window.

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage